# Python3 - How to add a name for editing in input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add a name for editing in input?

New name

```
name = input("New your name : ")
print(name)
New your name :
```

How to add a name for editing ? (edit the name Charles)

something like

```
edit = "Charles"
name = input("Edit your name : " + edit)
print(name)
Edit your name : Charles
```

Thank you to help..

Comment: What do you mean by editing your name?

Comment: He means pre-filling the line that you will type.

Comment: There is no way to do this with the Python builtin libraries without using 3rd party stuff.

Comment: I think the usual approach to this would be something like `name = input("Enter name (some default)") or "some default"`.

Comment: well it can be definitely done using tkinter gui but I am guessing you are looking for a command line option and not a gui one.

Comment: So it is bad, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Python was compiled with `readline` support, you can actually do it using only the standard library:

```
import readline

def make_pre_input_hook(default):

    def pre_input_hook():
        readline.insert_text(default)
        readline.redisplay()

    return pre_input_hook

readline.set_pre_input_hook(make_pre_input_hook('Charles'))

name = input('Edit your name: ')

print('You are now called {}.'.format(name))
```

Note that with Python 2, you'd need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Wow, super ;-) What is the license for the code ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that you ask ;-) Actually, there sort of is a license, since I "stole" it from a project of my own, `tl.cli` (to be found at PyPI), which is published under the ZPL, similar to the BSD license. Unfortunately, `tl.cli` has not been touched in a while and so is not Python-3 compatible, otherwise you could simply use it to get an even more comfortable prompt.

Comment: Licenses not know much, I can use or in your project?

Comment: Just use the code I posted without restrictions. Don't worry about my project, I just mentioned it because it might be of interest to Python-2 users.

Comment: Nice, did not know about that. But remember to do `readline.set_pre_input_hook(None)` afterwards.

Comment: True; it would actually be nice if there was a context manager that does this kind of thing. Maybe I add on to `tl.cli` if and when I get around to update it at some point.

Comment: @Thomas Lotze : I ran into a small problem. You can not pass a parameter. readline.set_pre_input_hook(pre_input_hook(default)). Solution other than superglobal variable ? Thank you.

Comment: You could use a closure to store the value, i.e. pass it to a function that then returns the hook function. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to do this with just the command line. Instead, I suggest providing some default value in parentheses, and using that in case the user does not enter any input. This is also much more common and requires fewer keystrokes from the user in case he wants to change the default (no need to delete).

```
>>> name = input("Enter name (some default): ") or "some default"
Enter name (some default): 
>>> name
'some default'
>>> name = input("Enter name (some default): ") or "some default"
Enter name (some default): foobar
>>> name
'foobar'
```

Here, the `or "some default"` has the effect that if the first part of the expression -- the result of `input` -- is empty, then the second part, i.e. the default value, is used.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
defaultname = 'Charles'
nameprompt = 'Enter your name, or just press Return to accept the default name.\nDefault Name: '+defaultname
name = input(nameprompt)
if name == '':
    name = defaultname
```